# how to change the height of the slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

please help to reduce the height of the slider, if at all possible 
 
Now slide the [page](http://prozaik.16mb.com/html5_2/gl/) height 395px, 200px and need 
 
I tried it in Photoshop to resize the source images, but the height of the slide on the page did not change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `.height()`

```
 $('.main.radius7').height(200);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a width to `.main-radius7`. Cant really add a demo because you didnt provide code but thats all you have to do.

Same thing goes for `height`.

So you will have something like:

```
.radius7{
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;                        
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px; 
    -khtml-border-radius: 7px;              
    border-radius: 7px;     
    width:  400px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just see your page where you have applied `height: auto;` in `.rslides img` which will not work. You need to define yourself like `height: 200px;`

Or, perhaps you might want to get responsive, so use `max-width: 100%;`